# What is the dating of the earliest manuscript of the Book of Arda Wiraz?

Tags: persia, religious-history, zoroastrianism

The [Arda Wiraz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Arda_Virafhttps://) is a Zoroastrian text that tells the story of a spiritual journey undertook by Wiraz. Wiki summarises the story as this:

> Wirāz is chosen for his piety to undertake a journey to the next world in order to prove the truth of Zoroastrian beliefs, after a period when the land of Iran had been troubled by the presence of confused and alien religions. He drinks a mixture of wine, mang, and Haoma, after which his soul travels to the next world. Here he is greeted by a beautiful woman named Dēn, who represents his faith and virtue. Crossing the Chinvat Bridge, he is then conducted by "Srosh, the pious and Adar, the yazad" through the "star track", "moon track" and "sun track" – places outside of heaven reserved for the virtuous who have nevertheless failed to conform to Zoroastrian rules. In heaven, Wirāz meets Ahura Mazda who shows him the souls of the blessed (ahlaw, an alternate Middle Persian version of the word ardā[4]). Each person is described living an idealised version of the life he or she lived on earth, as a warrior, agriculturalist, shepherd or other profession.[9] With his guides he then descends into hell to be shown the sufferings of the wicked. Having completed his visionary journey, Wirāz is told by Ahura Mazda that the Zoroastrian faith is the only proper and true way of life and that it should be preserved in both prosperity and adversity.
>
>  **[ Wikipedia: The Book of Arda Viraf ]**

My goal is finding the earliest manuscript of this specific book (the Book of Arda Wiraz), because it contains a story similar to [the Story of Isra' wal Miraj](https://sunnah.com/muslim:164a) found in Islam but the "Main Character" there is the Prophet Muhammad PBUH rather than Wiraz. (obviously) And I want to determine whether the Fire Worshippers of Persia wrote this narrative first, or the Muslims did, and determining the date of the earliest manuscript of The Book of Arda Wiraz is one part of that.

Both Wikipedia and the Encyclopaedia Iranica say the "final form" of the Book of Arda Wiraz was established in the 9th-10th Centuries.

> The Ardā Wīrāz-nāmag, like many of the Zoroastrian works, underwent successive redactions. `It assumed its definitive form in the 9th-10th centuries A.D.,` as may be seen in the text’s frequent Persianisms, usages known to be characteristic of early Persian literature (e.g., generalized use of the durative particle hamē). 
> **[ Encyclopaedia Iranica: Arda Wiraz ]**

But that does not inform about the datings of the earlier versions of this book.

I don't know where I would find a collection of the manuscripts of the book of Arda wiraz and hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I think it's because the question doesn't seem neutral. Calling them "Fire worshippers" instead of Zoroastrians almost seems insulting. Perhaps in altering the tone you'll get a better reception?

Comment: So you consider Fire worshipper to be an insult? This is actually quite disrespectful to the zoroastrians' honoured practise of fire worship. Please kindly retract your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Encyclopedia Iranica's [entry on Pahlavi literature](https://referenceworks.brillonline.com/entries/encyclopaedia-iranica-online/middle-persian-literature-i-pahlavi-literature-COM_787), the *oldest* *known* manuscripts of this work are two codices called "K20" and "M51".

K20 is a manuscript collection of several works in a single volume. It was acquired in Bombay around 1820 by Rasmus Rask, a Danish linguist, and it is currently in the Royal Library of Denmark. This, and other books collected at the same time, are collectively known as the [Codices Hafnienses](https://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/codices-hafnienses). A recent facsimile and English translation of its version of Arda Wiraz are available as *Ardā Wirāz Nāmag: The Iranian 'Divina Commedia'* by Fereydun Vahman (Routledge, 2016), and the entire collection is in *Codices Avestici et Pahlavici Bibliothecae Universitatis Hafniensis* (Copenhagen: Levin and Munksgaard), with K20 found in volume 1. One of the included texts is dated 1351, so the codex must have been put into its current form at some point after that year.

M51 apparently has a more certain date; it "was written in 766 Y./1397, by Pišotan Rām, and derives ultimately from a copy written by Mihrpānāg Srōšayār, Hērbad of Nēšābur", according to the Encyclopedia Iranica, and currently resides in the Bayerische Staatsbibliothek in Munich where they call it "Cod. Zend. 51a". It's also known as H6 in some scholarly sources because it used to be in the private possession of Martin Haug (a professor at Munich). There is no published edition of this manuscript, but it has been scanned and can be [read online](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/en/view/bsb00028015?page=,1) assuming you read the language. Additional discussion of this manuscript can be found in *Die Zendhandschriften der K. Hof- und Staatsbibliothek in München* by Christian Bartholomae (1915), p38-72, if you read German.

Additionally, Haug's edition ([*The Book of Arda Viraf: The Pahlavi Text*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Book_of_Arda_Viraf/GbtUAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), Martin Haug and E. H. West, 1872) includes more detail on these and other manuscript sources in its long introduction. More recent scholarship may have disagreed on some of the conclusions, but it doesn't look like any older extant manuscript has been unearthed.

None of this means that the text itself was composed in the late 14th century. Scholarly dating to the 9th or 10th centuries will be based on other historical and linguistic considerations, but since this is a 200-year span of time, it's evident that we don't have much data that would yield any more precise date.

Comment: what does this mean "was written in 766 Y./1397"  ?

Comment: 1397 AD or 766 years since Yazdegerd III became Shahanshah of the Sassanid empire - that is a conventional Zoroastrian way to count years